# How to get object position from a ray hit?

Tags: unity, c#, raycasting

I've been coding a program to teleport an object to a player hands(which is just and empty game object). I did this using ray collision on mouse down, but I cant think of a way to find the position of the object I'm trying to teleport. I'm using GameObject.Find to find position of the hands, but I wanted to know if there was a way to find the position of an object via a ray collision. If there isn't a way to find the position of an object from a ray collision what other way could I find its position.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class BasicCollisonSound : MonoBehaviour {
    public Transform hands;
    public Transform obj;

    void Start()
    {
        hand = GameObject.Find("Hand");
    }



    void Update () {
        if (Input.getkeydown("mouse1"))
        {

            Ray ray;
            RaycastHit hit;

            ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
            if(Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, 100.0f))
            {
                if (hit.collider.tag == "Grabbable")
                {

                    obj.position = hands.position;
                }
            }





        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `hit.transform` to access the [transform property](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RaycastHit-transform.html) of the object your ray hit. Then you can just set the position from there. (Code not tested, please comment on whether it works or not)

```
if(Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, 100.0f))
{
     if (hit.collider.tag == "Grabbable")
     {
          hit.transform.position = hands.position;
     }
}
```